# Put HTML tag and class within a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic button, that loads when a condition in the JavaScript is fulfilled.
When the Button loads, I need to invoke a function (ClickMe) which works as soon as I click the button.

Now the problem is I am not able to relate the function with the button.

In my code

```
    var showthelocation = "";

    showthelocation += '<li>';

    if (data.location == 'Sydney'){
    showthelocation += "</br><button class=\"" + ClickMe + "\">Show</button>";
    }

    showthelocation += '</li>';


    function ClickMe("Click"){
    //Some Code
    };

    $(".showthelocation").html(showthelocation);
```

and HTML

```
    <ul class="showthelocation"></ul>
```

I want to put a ID or Class to access it from the ClickMe function, not able to do it. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by *some* function?  Which function?

Comment: Really confusing. Try to explain it a little better. Anyway 3 tips to deal with DOM elements: jQuery, jQuery and jQuery.

Comment: `class='buttonClass'` inside your string?

Comment: "I want to put a ID or Class" where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not doing something like:

```
var showthelocation = "";
showthelocation += '<li>';

if (data.location == 'Sydney'){
  showthelocation += '<br /><button onclick="ClickMe();">Show</button>';
}

showthelocation += '</li>';

$(".showthelocation").html(showthelocation); 

function ClickMe(){
  console.log("Some Code");
};
```

Or more jQuery'sh

```
...
showthelocation += '<br /><button id="myButton">Show</button>';
...
$(".showthelocation").html(showthelocation);
$("#myButton").onclick(ClickMe);
```

This works, but if you have more buttons that will execute the same function you should go for a `class` instead of an `id`, for example:

```
...
showthelocation += '<br /><button class="myButton">Show</button>';
...
$(".showthelocation").html(showthelocation);
$(".myButton").onclick(ClickMe);
```

This would attach the click handler to all buttons with the class `myButton`.

Comment: One problem: I'm guessing his snippet is in the middle of some sort of larger function. ClickMe would need to be a globally-defined function outside this method. That could work, but...it's not especially future-proof.

Comment: Actually, there still might be two more problems. It's possible I'm thinking ahead; If he's actually showing a list of items, and intends to add others, then you can't use an id; use a class, or just a slightly longer query like my answer. Also, when you're setting id=etc inside a Javascript string, it works best if you mix single quotes with double, ie: += 'id="myId" ', or += "id='myId' ". Right now I'm not sure what error you'll get.

Comment: There are two problems.
1. The class is not identified in
          
            showthelocation += "</br><button class="myButton">Show</button>";

2. It says myButton is not defined

Comment: @usercode, see please my edit's I guess it was because `$(".showthelocation").html(showthelocation);` needs to be called before trying to attach the click handler

Comment: 1. The `</br>` which you (and the OP) wrote is incorrect: it should be `<br />`. 2. @Katana314 was right: your syntax is incorrect, that's why `"ClickMe()"`'s syntax highlight is bad: so you should write `showthelocation += '</br><button onclick="ClickMe();">Show</button>';` (see the apostrophe (`'`) instead of the quotation marks (`"`)!)

Comment: @Sk8erPeter explaining perfectly, of course, why this long answer has +2 and my very short one has 0.

Comment: @Katana314, sorry, I copied the original syntax, the errors where already there, now it should be correct...

Comment: @Sk8erPeter, thanks for pointing that out, I copied the orignal code and didn't see at first the `</br>` problem

Comment: @usercode I guess you should go for the jQuerysh method instead

Comment: @usercode: this can occur for example if you try to execute your code in the `<head>` section or at least above the elements, not after the elements have been rendered by the browser or after the DOM tree is ready. So you should execute your code bound to the [`ready` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). So maybe @intuitivepixel should also show the example that way to avoid this kind of misunderstandings.

Comment: @usercode, obviously the `ClickMe` function should not be inside any success Ajax callback, rather defined outside to be accessible

Comment: @usercode, I'm glad I could help, and by the way thanks for the edit!

Comment: My pleasure @intuitivepixel , learnt a lot with the simple error :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your issue is with the ClickMe function on each button. Right now it's just writing out some sort of "[Object function]" thing in the HTML, I'm guessing. I think the best solution would be with a multi-part assignment. Remove the onclick from the HTML itself, then...

```
$(".showthelocation").html(showthelocation);
$(".showthelocation li button").onclick(ClickMe);
```

This should add the handlers to any and all buttons created that way.

Comment: Yup, always nice to have a clearer question. I think my solution still works correctly though.